Using DOMPDF in Laravel10
After the installation process is finished, in order to properly register the service provider and alias, you should insert the following lines into the config/app.php file:
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
    // ...
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    // ...
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
],

However, it is important to note that an error may occur indicating that 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade' is an Undefined type.
I have verified that the domPDF package has been successfully installed.

What's the question?

it give that the at 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade' is an Undefined type.

INSTEAD OF
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

USE
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class,

INSIDE YOUR CONTROLLER:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf_view', $data);

